# Interpretation of 'against' in 'offend against'

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, objects

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/offend contains the definition.

> Are people whose jobs concern the fight against crime likely to be biased jurors? ... The court
>   decided that the presence of serving police officers and a prosecuting solicitor (an employee
>   of the Crown Prosecution Service) on separate juries in 2004 and 2005 had not **offended
>   against** *principles of fairness* and there were no circumstances in the cases to give rise to
>   concerns of bias.

Source: p 168, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Would someone please correct my initial 'gloss' on this verb + particle?

I attached **against** to *principles of fairness*, so
**offended against** *principles of fairness*
= **offended + against** *principles of fairness*
= offended + unfairness,
but this is the opposite meaning of **offended against** + *principles of fairness*.

1. What are the errors above? Are there terms for them?
2. When should the empty preposition or particle be parsed as above?

Comment: You should group **[offend against](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/offend)** together if you want to group them. The headword of the phrase *principles of fairness* is *principles* rather than *fairness*. They are *principles*. "Which principles?", you might well ask. They are *principles of fairness*.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching **against** to *principles of fairness* (as you wrote) just doesn't make sense. **Offend against** is a **phrasal verb**, as as such, must be treated as a unit. See e.g. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/offend-against-sth. Its meaning is different from a simple **offend**.

*Offended unfairness* is incorrect. A person can be offended (=they become upset/resentful), not a concept (like unfairness).